# React-Native: State is changed, but returning old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, activity-lifecycle

I have two components. There is a button on ComponentA, when you click on it, it changes the state:

```js
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'
.
.
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        filter: true,
    };
}
.
.
.
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=>{ this.setState({filter: !this.state.filter }); }}
>
    {this.state.filter ?
        <Text>Enabled</Text> :
        <Text>Disabled</Text>
    }
</TouchableOpacity>
.
.
.
<ComponentB filter={this.state.filter} />
```

```js
ComponentB

render(){
    return(
      <View><Text>{this.props.filter}</Text></View>
    );
}
```

Funny thing is, when you click on the button, the state does change and the text which is based on the state will also change. So at first time it changes from `True` to `False`. But ComponentB will receive still `True` instead of `False`.
When you click on it again, state changes from `False` to `True`, the text is also being shown correctly, but this time ComponentB will receive `True` instead of `False`.
Am I passing props to ComponentB wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what `ComponentB` is?

Comment: @BradBumbalough Please check the question I have updated it.

Comment: So is ComponentB always showing `True` no matter what?

Comment: @BradBumbalough
Initial state at Component A is True. When you click on Button first time, Button's text is being changed to False. means the state is false. but value True will be passed to ComponentB (while the value on component A is False)
And this continues. If state at A is True, B will receive False.
State value at ComponentB Won't stay same. it will change, but it always receives wrong value.

Comment: Ok thats what I assumed but your last line in the posts reads "ComponentB will receive True instead of False".. I think those need to be switched, correct?

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough,
At first load, initial state is True. True is also passed to Component B.
You click on button, state changes to False, but Component B again receive True.

You click again, state changes to FALSE, B receives TRUE
You click again, state changes to TRUE, B Receives FALSE.

And This continues this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your setState out of the view;

```js
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'
.
.
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        filter: true,
    };
}
changeFilter = () => { this.setState({filter: !this.state.filter }); };
.
.
.
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=> this.changeFilter(); }
>
    {this.state.filter ?
        <Text>Enabled</Text> :
        <Text>Disabled</Text>
    }
</TouchableOpacity>
.
.
.
<ComponentB filter={this.state.filter} />
```

Comment: Actually in the code, setState is out of view. to make it simple i write it here inside the view.
State is being changed properly in Component A, but wrong value is being passed to Component B

Comment: @Ataomega based on your code example, `setState` is called in view.. can you update the example accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You need To pass state in on `onPress`

like

```js
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'
.
.
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        filter: true,
    };
}
changeFilter = (filter) => { this.setState({filter: !filter }); };
.
.
.
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=> this.changeFilter(this.state.filter); }
>
    {this.state.filter ?
        <Text>Enabled</Text> :
        <Text>Disabled</Text>
    }
</TouchableOpacity>
.
.
.
<ComponentB filter={this.state.filter} />
```

Comment: While this may work, I don't think that's the problem. You shouldn't need to pass your state into the functions from the view.

Answer (score 1):

ComponentB

```
state = {
 filter: this.props.filter
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if(this.props.filter !== nextProps.filter){
   this.setState({
     filter: nextProps.filter
   })
 }
}

render(){
 return(
  <Text>{this.state.filter}</Text>
 );
}
```

this might solve your issue of props not updating when parent state gets changed.